# Display Html content between products (every 4 products) for Magento 2

Tags: magento2

How can i display a banner or html content between every 4 products in magento 2?

Like i have 4 products then i have a wide banner where it says, did you know we offer free shipping? or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

In you themes list.phtml

```
<MagentoBase>\app\design\frontend\<Vendor>\<Theme>\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\list.phtml
```

Replace you logic with `------ ADD HTML CONTENT ADDING LOGIC HERE ------` in below template

```
   ...
    ...
            <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
            ...
            ...
                <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="item product product-item">' : '</li> ------ ADD HTML CONTENT ADDING LOGIC HERE ------<li class="item product product-item">' ?>
                    ...
                    ...
                <?php endforeach; ?>
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this logic, but it breaks, i found it from magento 1 thread. i don't know what to do

: <?php if($i % 3 == 0){ ?>
<div id="banner">
-- Banner here --
</div>           
<?php } ?>